# Can I run another file from this file while passing in self as argument

Tags: python

I was wondering if something like this is possible in python where i am passing self as an argument to run another file

```
class AI():
    def__init__(self):
        os.system("file2.py",args=self)
```

Comment: Any reason you're not doing this the normal way? Like, import a module and call a function from it?

Comment: self is not an manually passed argument. It is given by default due to init being a class method. You would call this init message by simply importing this py file and creating an instance of the AI class

Comment: I'm trying to make a virtual assistant which when idle starts another script which can use the main script
That is why i tried to pass self as an argument for the script to start